# Set initial text when editing a QTableView cell

Tags: qt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I've subclassed QAbstractTableModel and overrode the flags() method so that some of the table cells are editable. The problem is that when I start editing, the existing cell value is erased. I would like to initially have the existing cell value selected. How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution is to handle Qt::EditRole when overriding data(). I was previously only handling Qt::DisplayRole.

Comment: You could also use a delegate and set it in `setEditorData`.